# How to prevent access to HDD during Live-CD operation?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, hard-disk, kernel-parameters

I want to safely disable the harddrive / harddisc (HDD) of my computer with boot parameters.

- I can not physically unplug it.
- BIOS / UEFI does not provide me an option to disable it.

Can I use the Kernel boot parameters to safely disable the harddrive, so the Live-CD I am booting cannot read / write / modify / access my harddrive?

Comment: Try the libata.force param, e.g. `libata.force=2.00:disable`.  Full details at https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt

Comment: @steve No success.

Comment: @user3200534 You could also try using for RHEL 6 the syntax is `blacklist=ahci dd`
for RHEL 7 the syntax is `modprobe.blacklist=ahci inst.dd` one of those should work on all distros by the way.